# Stack Overflow plug-in for Visual Studio?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, addon

Do you know if anybody has ever created a plug-in to access Stack Overflow from Visual Studio?

I'd like to be able to search, answer, and vote for Q&As from within the IDE.

Comment: Did you decide you no longer want to be productive?

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this? All that creating a Stack Overflow plug-in for Visual Studio would do is encourage people to ask questions before debugging their code or reading the applicable documentation. And, on the other site, it would encourage them to simply copy and paste code from answers into their projects, rather than thinking through and trying to *understand* what it does. Overall, a **terrible** idea.

Comment: I think it is a fascinating idea although not much need due to the excellent browsers we have these days

Comment: OMG ! what's a controversial question...

Answer (score 14):

To answer, vote on Stack Overflow, you need a web browser for now.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 for the answer, but tempted to -1 because you are still using VS2008...

Answer (score 4):

Did a search on: [www.stackapps.com](http://www.stackapps.com)

This is the only vstudio plugin that I found:

[StackOverflow Notifications in Visual Studio 2010 Extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/1696/stackoverflow-notifications-in-visual-studio-2010-extension)

Answer (score 0):

VSCommands has a toolbar and notifications.  I have VSC but I don't use the toolbar, so I'm not sure exactly what it does.

http://vscommands.com/features/